# Phaser 3: Change width of sprite relative to height

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'd like to be able to change the height of my sprite to fit into a menu, however when I change the height with `sprite.displayHeight = menu.height`, it's width won't scale along and it will be stretched/squashed.

Is there a way to scale the width relative to the height, to keep the sprite's original ratio?

Comment: Just calculate the proper width and also set that? What exactly is the issue? The sprite dimensions are fixed, and thus so is the ratio, which makes this a simply multiplication.

Comment: I suppose that is an option. I mostly wanted to ask in case there already is a specific method to make this much easier, given that Phaser is a very large framework and it can be hard to find certain things sometimes.

Comment: I guess you can also calculate the scaling factor instead, then scale the sprite. That should keep the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know any *special* function, that does this out-of-the-box, **BUT** you can achieve this, with only one extra *line of code.* **No extra calculation needed.**
*(this works also with the `displayHeight`)*

1. First set the **width** of the image: `img.displayWidth = 100;`
2. Then set the **scale** of the Y axis (since the X-axis is set through setting the `displayWidth`): `img.scaleY = img.scaleX;`

> Here [the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite.html#displayWidth__anchor), that points this out:
>
> *"...The displayed width of this Game Object.
>
> This value takes into account the scale factor.
>
> Setting this value will adjust the Game Object's scale property..."*

**Here a working demo:**

```js
// Minor formating for stackoverflow
document.body.style = "display: flex;flex-direction: column;";    

function preload ()
{
    this.load.image('img', 'https://labs.phaser.io/assets/pics/contra3.png');
}

function create ()
{
    let imgOrig = this.add.image(100,100, 'img');
    let img = this.add.image(320, 100, 'img');
    img.displayWidth = 100;

    // extra line to scale the image proportional
    img.scaleY = img.scaleX;
}

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 160,
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create
    }
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the kind of thing I was thinking of :D I prefer this much over having to calculate the scale myself!